# How to remove bubbling effect in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a demo in which I have one row above which I have flip button .I want alert will display only when user click on row.
But some time it display alert when user click on flip button?
http://jsfiddle.net/9mLEj/9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#rowClick').click(function(){
     alert('--')   
    })


})
```

Comment: when you already know what bubbling is, how hard can it be to google that exact question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevent event bubble up the DOM tree:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rowClick').click(function () {
        alert('--')
    })

    $('#sliderClick').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
})
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mLEj/11/)

---

Seem like jQuery mobile has changed the structure of your HTML markup, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rowClick').click(function () {
        alert('--')
    })

    $('#rowClick .ui-slider').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mLEj/15/)**

Comment: It is not working any browser.Please  click the circle of flip button

Comment: please click the circle of flip button it show alert

Comment: @user3530755 Could be an incompatibility somehow.

Comment: can you please elaborate ? Actually when I click on flip button (circle ) it display alert

Comment: @user3530755 I know it does, beats me why. It seemed to be an issue in the past but it's said to be solved.

Comment: @flex thanks man working..Can "test" text is front of flip button ?

Comment: So you want to position `Test` overlap the button?